# Timeout in IO operation

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I was using a query which pulled back a large amount of populated navigation properties. Essentially it looked like this:

```
using( var context = new MyApplicationContext() )
{
    DbSet<BaseTable> dbSet = context.Set<BaseTable>();
    IQueryable<BaseTable> query = dbSet;

    query = query.Include(entity => entity.T.C);
    query = query.Include(entity => entity.TC.Select(tc => tc.T.M));
    query = query.Include(entity => entity.TC);
    query = query.Include(entity => entity.W.FW.F.S);
    query = query.Include(entity => entity.W.FW.P);
    query = query.Include(entity => entity.W.PL.P);
    query = query.Include(entity => entity.W.PL);
    query = query.Include(entity => entity.W.E);
    query = query.Include(entity => entity.E);

    query = query.Where( set of conditions );

    List<BaseTable> Loaded = query.ToList();
}
```

However, running this code produced an error

> **Timeout in IO operation**
>   [TimeoutException: Timeout in IO operation]
>      MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.StopTimer() +168
>      MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +148
>      System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +262
>      MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +86
>      MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket() +110
>      MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() +59
>      MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId) +100
>      MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId) +54
>      MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force) +145
>      MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult() +524
>      MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +1939

How can I allow this query to have enough time to load?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you need to do is increase the command timeout property.

In entity framework, the context used inherits from [`DbContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.113%29.aspx). This is an `IObjectContextAdapter` but does not contain easy access to the `ObjectContext` methods. As such, in order to access the command timeout property, you will need to go through the [`Database`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) property of the `DbContext`.

```
using( var context = new MyApplicationContext() )
{
    DbSet<BaseTable> dbSet = context.Set<BaseTable>();
    IQueryable<BaseTable> query = dbSet;
```

> ```
>    //set an increased command timeout by accessing Database property
>    //on the context
>    context.Database.CommandTimeout = 300;//in seconds (5 minutes)
> ```

```
    query = query.Include(entity => entity.T.C);
    query = query.Include(entity => entity.TC.Select(tc => tc.T.M));
    query = query.Include(entity => entity.TC);
    query = query.Include(entity => entity.W.FW.F.S);
    query = query.Include(entity => entity.W.FW.P);
    query = query.Include(entity => entity.W.PL.P);
    query = query.Include(entity => entity.W.PL);
    query = query.Include(entity => entity.W.E);
    query = query.Include(entity => entity.E);

    query = query.Where( set of conditions );

    List<BaseTable> Loaded = query.ToList();
}
```

Now your query can have the time it needs in order to pull a larger amount of data if necessary.

Comment: do you know if it's sufficient to specify the Default Command Timeout in the connection string? Or must it also be specified as you showed above?

Comment: @chriszumberge - This is just to show a variable setting in code. You can also set it in the connection string, but the idea was that you probably don't always want this long timeout to be set.

Answer (score 2):

use this code in your Connection String in web.config

"`default command timeout=0`"

```
 "server=localhost;Database=Database;uid=;pwd=;Allow User Variables=True;Convert Zero Datetime=True;default command timeout=0"
```